# Python/Pandas - Is there a way to make mean() return NaN when there is only one value to calculate?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a hypothetical example of how my data frame looks like,

```
>>df
    1A   1B   1C   2A   2B   2C   3A    3B    3C   
P1  11   13   15   11   9.7  12   12.3  22.6  22.4 
P2  11   0    15   0    0    12   0     0     0    
P3  NaN  25   12   NaN  NaN  12   NaN   NaN   NaN  
P4  11   NaN  12   9    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  
P5  11   NaN  NaN  NaN  12   NaN  NaN   NaN   12.3
```

I'm currently averaging every three columns in each row by using

```
df_avg = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//3, axis=1).mean()
```

Which will give me the resulting data frame,

```
    0       1       2
P1  13.0    10.9    19.1
P2  8.7     4.0     0.0
P3  18.5    12.0    NaN
P4  11.5    9.0     NaN
P5  11.0    12.0    12.3
```

The mean() appears to divide by two when there are only 2 values and 1 NaN, which is what I want.
Plus, those with 3 NaN returns NaN and that is also good.

However, the last value of P5 is 12.3 which is from having two NaN and 12.3 as the only value (same in other cases).
That is not an average and I wish to remove any sites with 2 NaNs or make it return NaN.

What would be the best way to preserve this
"average every group of 3 cells" + "divide groups with 2 values and one NaN with 2" + "groups with three NaN should return NaN"
*and* make it also do "group with only one real value and two NaN return NaN"?

One way I could think of was to use the output of `np.arange(len(df.columns))//3` to make a new row, then make a function that uses `groupby` and `mean` with the conditions I want; however, my skill isn't quite up there to understand how that code should roughly look like. And this doesn't seem like the easiest way to do this in my novice guess.

Sorry for the hassle and thank you in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `min_count`

```
g=df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//3, axis=1)
g.sum(min_count=2)/g.count()
Out[213]: 
            0     1     2
P1  13.000000  10.9  19.1
P2   8.666667   4.0   0.0
P3  18.500000   NaN   NaN
P4  11.500000   NaN   NaN
P5        NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Applied this on my actual dataframe, as far as I can check so far, it looks like this works! Thank you. Currently trying to check to make sure if this worked 100% as intended!

Answer (score 2):

We can get booleans back with [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and check if the [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) over the row axis (`axis=1`) is greater than or equal (`ge`) `2`, in other words, if the amount of `NaN` per group `>= 2`. If so we `mask` them with `NaN`:

```
grps = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//3, axis=1)
mask = grps.apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum(axis=1)).ge(2)

df = grps.mean().mask(mask)
```

```
       0     1     2
P1 13.00 10.90 19.10
P2  8.67  4.00  0.00
P3 18.50   nan   nan
P4 11.50   nan   nan
P5   nan   nan   nan
```

Comment: This method also works! Thank you. It appears that the output from this method agrees with the above ones, so this is really helpful. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's an built-in function. Here's a quick-fix:

```
m = (df.T.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//3)  # transpose and groupby because
       .agg(['count', 'mean'])                    # agg only allows groupby with axis=0
       .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)                    # make 'count' and 'mean' first level for easy access
       .T                                         # transpose back
    )

df_avg = m.loc['mean'].mask(m.loc['count']==1, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
            0     1     2
P1  13.000000  10.9  19.1
P2   8.666667   4.0   0.0
P3  18.500000   NaN   NaN
P4  11.500000   NaN   NaN
P5        NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This also appears to be working flawlessly! All the NaNs are in the same place as the other methods. Thank you!